# Smallest Number in JS

Tags: javascript

According to MDN, the Number.MIN_VALUE property represents the smallest positive numeric value representable in JavaScript, then how come 1/Number.MIN_VALUE = Infinity ?

Comment: what would you think it should be? It is close to 0 and what is 1/0?

Comment: So what is the smallest number you can divide without getting Infinity?

Comment: In theory, it should be `1/Number.MAX_VALUE`. But floating point division isn't perfect, so `1/(1/Number.MAX_VALUE)` actually evaluates to infinity. I'm curious why you need this value.

Comment: @triver The smallest number you can divide without getting Infinity is `Number.MIN_VALUE`. This works fine: `1e-323/Number.MIN_VALUE === 2`. Do you mean specifically the smallest number you can divide `1` by?

Comment: That would be `5.56268464626801e-309`

Comment: @Paulpro Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my browser, `Number.MIN_VALUE` evaluates to `5e-324`. So when you do `1/Number.MIN_VALUE`, you would expect to get `2e323`. But that's too large for Javascript to represent -- `Number.MAX_VALUE` is approximately `1.8e308`. So it gets truncated to `infinity`.

Comment: Just as an additional note for the reason why numbers can get so small compared to how big they can get - look into subnorm/denorm of IEEE754.

Answer (score 1):

Number.MIN_VALUE is `5e-324`.

`1/5e-324` would be `2e323` if there was enough precision to represent the exact result, but there is not:

```js
console.log( 2e323 === Infinity )
```

Number.MAX_VALUE is `1.7976931348623157e+308`.

`2e323` is approximately 1,000,000,000,000,000 times larger than that.

Answer (score -1):

1 divided by small amount of number = very big number

1 / 0.00000000001 = 10000000000

1 / 0.0000000000000000000000000000001 = 10000000000000000000000000000000

The smaller the divisor, the bigger the quotient.

approaching very large numbers is represented by Infinity.